# ¿Cómo puedo reportar un error del IDE netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, log

Recientemente vi [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/558073/netbeans-12-4-no-me-permite-abrir-los-archivo-java-al-seleccionarlos-me-abre-y) en la que parece que alguien hallo un error en el IDE netbeans, así que me gustaría saber cómo reportar un error de manera oficial, básicamente que archivos se deben de agregar en cada caso y para qué sirve cada uno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recientemente se cambiaron de JIRA a github issues, se puede reportar un incidente en la liga:

> https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues

El registro de eventos se halla en:

```
C:\Users\<TU_NOMBRE_DE_USUARIO>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\14\var\log
```

Te recomiendo borrar todos los archivos y luego intentar abrir tu IDE y reproducir el error.

Mediante sus extensiones podrás detectar algunos archivos relevantes por ejemplo:

1. `.log` contienen un registro de eventos desde que inicia hasta que termina la ejecución. Es la traza de errores que estamos acostumbrados a ver los desarrolladores Java.
2. `.dump` contienen una traza de error más específica con como reproducirla, se generan cundo hay errores en el IDE.
3. carpeta `heapdump.hprof` estos son los archivos de volcado de tu máquina virtual, normalmente solo son revisados por expertos ya que contienen información de los valores en el registro de memoria actualmente
4. archivos `uigestures` contienen un registro de eventos en formato XML de interfaz gráfica, y es útil para los que corrigen los errores ya que les indica que acciones deben llevar a cabo paso por paso dentro del IDE para reproducir algún error en caso de que fuera una condición especifica

***Ejemplo de archivo .dump:***

```
package com.github.javatlacati.respuestasstackoverflow.questions553067;

public class NewClass {
    bool creciente(int aJ int

    
        ){

return a < bi

        bool decreciente
        (int a int b)T

        return a }
    bi

    void ordenarVector(int iVector[] int iTamanio

    bool criterio(int int

    
        )) {
int iAuxj

        ror(int i = ej i< iTamanioi i
    

    
        ++} {
ror(int i = ej i< iTamanioi i
    

    
        ++} {
ror(in j = li + l
    }
    j j

    {
        iTamanio j
    

    
        ++} {

ir(criterio(iVecor[j] iVecor[i])
iAux ± iVecorCj
        ]j iVecor[j] = iVecor[i]
        j iVecor[i
        ] = iAuxj This text was recognized by the built
        -in Ocrad engine.A better transcription may be attained by right clicking on the selection and changing the OCR engine to "Tesseract" (under the "Language" menu
        ). This message can be removed in the future by unchecking "OCR Disclaimer" (under the Options menu
        ). More info
        : http://projectnaptha.com/ocrad
    
}

----- Classpath: ---------------------------------------------
bootPath: nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.base/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.compiler/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.datatransfer/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.desktop/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.instrument/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.logging/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.management/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.management.rmi/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.naming/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.net.http/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.prefs/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.rmi/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.scripting/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.se/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.security.jgss/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.security.sasl/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.smartcardio/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.sql/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.sql.rowset/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.transaction.xa/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.xml/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/java.xml.crypto/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.accessibility/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.attach/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.charsets/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.compiler/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.crypto.cryptoki/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.crypto.ec/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.crypto.mscapi/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.dynalink/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.editpad/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.hotspot.agent/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.httpserver/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.incubator.foreign/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.incubator.vector/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.internal.ed/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.internal.jvmstat/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.internal.le/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.internal.opt/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.internal.vm.ci/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.internal.vm.compiler/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.jartool/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.javadoc/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.jcmd/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.jconsole/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.jdeps/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.jdi/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.jdwp.agent/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.jfr/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.jlink/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.jpackage/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.jshell/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.jsobject/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.jstatd/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.localedata/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.management/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.management.agent/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.management.jfr/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.naming.dns/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.naming.rmi/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.net/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.nio.mapmode/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.random/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.sctp/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.security.auth/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.security.jgss/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.unsupported/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.unsupported.desktop/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.xml.dom/;nbjrt:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-18.0.2/!/modules/jdk.zipfs/
classPath: C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\com\github\javafaker\javafaker\1.0.2\javafaker-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.11\commons-lang3-3.11.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\snakeyaml-1.23-android.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\com\github\mifmif\generex\1.0.2\generex-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\dk\brics\automaton\automaton\1.11-8\automaton-1.11-8.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.20\lombok-1.18.20.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\com\github\julianhyde\linq4j\v0.1.8\linq4j-v0.1.8.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\30.1-jre\guava-30.1-jre.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\failureaccess\1.0.1\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\listenablefuture\9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava\listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.5.0\checker-qual-3.5.0.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.3.4\error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.3\j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\reactor-core\3.4.0\reactor-core-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.3\reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\usuario\Documents\NetBeansProjects\respuestasstackoverflow\target\classes
sourcePath: C:\Users\usuario\Documents\NetBeansProjects\respuestasstackoverflow\src\main\java;C:\Users\usuario\Documents\NetBeansProjects\respuestasstackoverflow\src\main\resources;C:\Users\usuario\Documents\NetBeansProjects\respuestasstackoverflow\src\main\resources
----- Original exception ---------------------------------------------
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.analyze(JavacTaskImpl.java:383)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.JavacParser.moveToPhase(JavacParser.java:770)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.JavacParser.getResult(JavacParser.java:540)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.JavacParser.getResult(JavacParser.java:141)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callGetResult(TaskProcessor.java:608)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.SourceCache.getResult(SourceCache.java:239)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$RequestPerformer.run(TaskProcessor.java:775)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:279)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$RequestPerformer.execute(TaskProcessor.java:702)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$CompilationJob.run(TaskProcessor.java:663)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:155)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.check(Assert.java:46)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AliveAnalyzer.clearPendingExits(Flow.java:586)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AliveAnalyzer.visitClassDef(Flow.java:541)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:819)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:444)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AliveAnalyzer.analyzeTree(Flow.java:964)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AliveAnalyzer.analyzeTree(Flow.java:956)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow.analyzeTree(Flow.java:220)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.flow(JavaCompiler.java:1377)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.flow(JavaCompiler.java:1341)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.analyze(JavacTaskImpl.java:404)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$analyze$1(JavacTaskImpl.java:379)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper(JavacTaskImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.analyze(JavacTaskImpl.java:379)
    ... 15 more
```

***Ejemplo de archivo uigestures:***

```
<record>
  <date>2020-11-17T14:08:52</date>
  <millis>1605643732662</millis>
  <sequence>38</sequence>
  <logger>org.netbeans.ui.focus</logger>
  <level>500</level>
  <thread>40</thread>
  <message>LOG_WINDOW_ACTIVATED</message>
  <key>LOG_WINDOW_ACTIVATED</key>
  <catalog>org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.Bundle</catalog>
  <param>307</param>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2020-11-17T14:08:52</date>
  <millis>1605643732846</millis>
  <sequence>39</sequence>
  <logger>org.netbeans.ui.metrics.projects</logger>
  <level>800</level>
  <thread>36</thread>
  <message>USG_START_PAGE_LINK</message>
  <key>USG_START_PAGE_LINK</key>
  <catalog>org.netbeans.modules.welcome.resources.Bundle</catalog>
  <param>RecentProject</param>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2020-11-17T14:08:55</date>
  <millis>1605643735889</millis>
  <sequence>42</sequence>
  <logger>org.netbeans.ui.maven.project</logger>
  <level>800</level>
  <thread>40</thread>
  <message>UI_MAVEN_PROJECT_OPENED</message>
  <key>UI_MAVEN_PROJECT_OPENED</key>
  <catalog>&lt;null&gt;</catalog>
  <param>jar</param>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2020-11-17T14:08:55</date>
  <millis>1605643735890</millis>
  <sequence>43</sequence>
  <logger>org.netbeans.ui.metrics.maven</logger>
  <level>800</level>
  <thread>40</thread>
  <message>USG_PROJECT_OPEN_MAVEN</message>
  <param>jar</param>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2020-11-17T14:08:56</date>
  <millis>1605643736021</millis>
  <sequence>44</sequence>
  <logger>org.netbeans.ui.projects</logger>
  <level>700</level>
  <thread>40</thread>
  <message>UI_OPEN_PROJECTS</message>
  <key>UI_OPEN_PROJECTS</key>
  <catalog>org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.Bundle</catalog>
  <param>org.netbeans.modules.maven.NbMavenProjectImpl</param>
  <param>NbMavenProjectImpl</param>
  <param>1</param>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2020-11-17T14:08:56</date>
  <millis>1605643736021</millis>
  <sequence>45</sequence>
  <logger>org.netbeans.ui.metrics.projects</logger>
  <level>800</level>
  <thread>40</thread>
  <message>USG_PROJECT_OPEN</message>
  <param>org.netbeans.modules.maven.NbMavenProjectImpl</param>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2020-11-17T14:08:56</date>
  <millis>1605643736406</millis>
  <sequence>46</sequence>
  <logger>org.netbeans.ui.indexing</logger>
  <level>800</level>
  <thread>39</thread>
  <message>INDEXING_STARTED</message>
  <key>INDEXING_STARTED</key>
  <catalog>org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.Bundle</catalog>
  <param>0</param>
</record>
```