# Apache NetBeans (mac) colapsa luego de instalar un plugin

Tags: netbeans, macos, plugin

Tengo este problema con mi Apache NetBeans 15 en mi Mac.
Le instalé un nuevo plugin (para cambiar a modo oscuro la interface) y al reiniciar el programa este ya no funciona más. Abre con una pantalla gris extraña y no me deja hacer más nade en él. Lo desinstalé con el AppCleaner y lo volví a instalar, pero el problema persiste...
No encuentro dónde eliminar el supuesto plugin conflictivo en el OS ni cómo hacer una desinstalación más profunda.
¿Alguna idea que me pueda ayudar a resolverlo?
Muchas gracias!!
Saludos!
Ignacio

Comment: Posiblemente relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/558083/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-reportar-un-error-del-ide-netbeans

Comment: ¿Es el mismo plugin de [ésta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/567643/problemas-con-netbeans-15-en-macos#comment1004212_567643)? .

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION !! MAC
hermano tengo la solución, desinstala el netbeans, eliminando las carpetas al basurero, luego vas al disco duro Macintosh HD, click derecho y abrir en terminal y ahí ejecutas los siguientes comandos:

COMANDS TERMINAL

rm -rf ~/.netbeans

rm rf~/Library/Application\Support/NetBeans

rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/NetBeans

rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/org.netbeans*

Luego que ejercitar los comandos no te dará respuesta el terminal, o sea no te mostrara algo como "removido con éxito" simplemente los pones y ya, también ponlos en el terminal normal sin abrirlo en Macintosh HD.
instalas de nuevo la ultima versión o la versión que tenias dañada y listo se quita, si tienes dudas me dices respondo rápido

Comment: Por favor has el [tour] y lee [answer]