Error ejecutando el clean an build en netbeans: Cannot run program "cmd"
Buen día,
Estoy ejecutando el clean an build en netbeans sobre un proyecto X y la respuesta de la consulta es el siguiente error el cual no he logrado determinar el motivo.
Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "D:\repositorio\integracion\contabilidad"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: "D:\repositorio\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn.cmd" -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.ext.class.path="C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 clean install


Hola William, bienvenido, puedes ejecutar tu programa (Run-Run File)?, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el nombre del programa, de la clase principal (que tiene el método "main") y el árbol de directorios?.

con la información que proporcionas el problema no se puede reproducir. ¿Podrías compartirnos más información? También te recomiendo revisar la información de la pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/558083/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-reportar-un-error-del-ide-netbeans
